# Is the following possible when initiating an if pictureBox clicked event?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a matching game and I recently learned that the following is possible:

```
if (checkBox1.checked = true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("For Example.")'
}
```

Then why is the following not possible?

```
   private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
       MessageBox.Show("Now Pick Another Hidden Picture!");
       pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        if (pictureBox13.Click = true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Great!");
            pictureBox13.Visible = false;

            double score = score + 1;
            textBox1.Text = (score).ToString();             
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try Again!");
            pictureBox13.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        } 
    }
```

There is a error line under .Click , and the error is :

The event 'system.Windows.Forms.Control.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=.

What does this mean? And why does this work for checking checkboxes, but not for clicking pictureboxes? Thank in advance.

Comment: Click is an Event, not a boolean variable.. and to check if a boolean equals a value you type ==, not =

Comment: You can set up a `Click` event for the `PictureBox`, but you cannot simply use it like a boolean.

Comment: I don't understand why. Isn't a boolean value true/false, and this code says that either the picturebox is clicked (true) or it isn't (false).

Comment: why do you think that `pictureBox13.Click` indicates that "the picturebox is clicked or it isn't"?

Comment: `Checked` is a property and can be true or false.  `Click` is an action (with a very small 'a') - ie it is something that is "done"

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean. @Igor

Comment: "Yes." does not answer "Why?"

Comment: Sorry. I thought that because true and false are only two possible outcomes, and what I am attempting only had two possible outcomes. @Igor

Comment: @D.Dude another way to explain it would be that it like the difference between a verb and an adjective - 'Click' cannot be true, 'Clicked' could be.

Answer (score 1):

`Checked` is the *state* of a checkbox. At any given time, a checkbox is either checked or unchecked. Reading `myCheckBox.Checked` immediately returns the *current* state of the checkbox.

`Click` is an *event*. What do you expect `if (pictureBox.Click == true)` to do? Tell you if the pictureBox has been clicked within the last X seconds? Wait X seconds for the user to click (or not click) on the pictureBox?

In other words: If you check a checkbox, it stays checked until it is unchecked. Thus, it makes sense to check the *current state* of the checkbox. On the other hand, if you click a button, it is "clicked" for only an instant and then returns to being "unclicked". Thus, it just does not make sense to query the "clicked" state of a button.

PS: Comparisons are done with `==`, not with `=`. The latter is an assigment. And, as Hugh correctly points out in the comments, `if (boolean)` is enough, `if (boolean == true)` is redundant.

Comment: ... and, for that matter `if (checkBox1.checked)` is sufficient

Comment: So do you think is it possible to program a bunch of checkBoxes to make pictureBoxes visible or invisible?

Comment: @D.Dude: This might be an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661). I suggest that you start a new question and explain exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Just wondering, what's the purpose of downvoting? I understand that some questions like mine are not the greatest, by why the hate?

Comment: @D.Dude: Apparently, two people thought that the question is unclear or not useful. It's not hate, just a different opinion. I know it's not easy, but try not to take it personally.